# Is accepting prize money from playing table tennis(or similar sports) haram or halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Is accepting money from winning table tennis(or similar sports) tournament haram or halal?what if I paid an entry fee or what if I did not pay any entry fee to the tournament? thanks?